# Setting up a server to run a geth node - what hardware would you recommend?

Tags: go-ethereum, cpp-ethereum

I am planning to run a geth node 24/7 on a server, what hardware specs would you recommend for this?

I'd like to download the chain pretty fast and want the block download to be consistently quick.

What processor/mainboard is doing the job here? 
If I am understanding this correctly, a good SSD and fast RAM are the main components I will have to spend lots of money on, correct?

If someone has more insight on how their server runs a geth node, I would happily listen to it as I have never in my life possessed a server so I don't even know how to connect to it via my PC (This one might be pretty easy though).

Thanks :)

Comment: possible duplicate https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/50455/minimum-theoretical-hardware-requirement-for-geth